# Function is not using getopt correctly

Tags: c++

The `getopt` function in this code is not working. I have tried to put code at the bottom to see what it is printing out as those values. I am inputting things into the code like `-c 1 txt.txt`. It does not even go through the `getopt` function at all because `i` remains the same even though it should be increased by one if the function works properly.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string>
#include "more.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int op;
    int buff = 1000;
    int bytesread = 10;
    int i = 3;
    int c = 0;
    ssize_t nr = 0;
    string v;
    v = argv[i];
    while ((op = getopt(argc, argv, "s:n:c:r:xb") != -1)) {
        switch(op)
        {
        case 's':
            buff = atoi(optarg);
            i++;
            break;
        case 'n':
            bytesread = atoi(optarg);
            i++;
            break;
        case 'c':
            c++;
            i++;
            v = *argv[i];
            cout << v << endl;
            op = atoi(optarg);
            cipher(v, buff, bytesread, op);
            break;
        case 'r':
            i++;
            v = argv[i];
            op = atoi(optarg);
            rotation(v, buff, bytesread, op);
            break;
        case 'x':
            i++;
            v = argv[i];
            hexa(v, buff, bytesread);
            break;
        case 'b':
            v = argv[i];
            i++;
            binary(v, buff, bytesread);
            break;
        case '?':
            int  buffer[1048];
            int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
            if (fd == -1) {
                perror("opening file");
                exit(1);
            }
            do {
                nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
                if (nr == -1) {
                    perror("reading file");
                    exit(1);                            
            }
            write(1,buffer,nr);
            } while (nr != 0);
            close(fd);
            break;      
        }   

    }
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your parens aren't right.  You're assigning the result of the comparison of the return value from getopt with -1 to `op`, which will be either 0 or 1.

Comment: I do not understand when you say my parens arent right?

Comment: If we ignore the arguments to getopt, you have `(op = getopt != -1)`, and it should be `(op = getopt) != -1`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much I understand now